# 2 div beside and 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have different divs one after the other in a vertical way. I mean that the user must use the scroll to go from one to another. But all that divs are 100% width and hight even when the user change the size of the window. I have seen that in some webs and I do not know how to do that.

I simplify this here: http://jsfiddle.net/bgWzb/

In this case the divs are 100% but are one under the other and I try to put #first then #second. The user should the scroll to see #second. How can I do that? I could use jQuery if necessary.

```
body{ margin:0; padding:0; }

#first{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:blue;
}

#second{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for position absolute is to set left and top to `0`, to get one div under the other you need to set the top to `100%` on one of them as they are out of the document flow, or use position relative (which would cause other issues with empty elements, the body not having a position etc) :

```
#second{
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgWzb/1/)

Comment: @ABFORCE the question CLEARY states 2 divs!

Comment: @adeneo top:100% is perfect, thank you!. I do not understand your comment about using position relative? Just for curiosity I have try it and I do not see how it could work.

Comment: @Nrc - thanks, if the answer helped you out, feel free to accecpt it! Setting position relative automatically places the elements below each other as they are then in the document flow, but to make that work, the body and html tags must have 100% height and width as well, have at look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgWzb/5/) ...

Comment: adeneo and thgaskell solutions are both equally very good. The system do not let me accept both. I do not know what criteria to use in this case?

Comment: Select whatever helped you the most, I didn't see the other answer when I posted the fiddle above, but if you went with position relative like in the answer from @thgaskell accept that one, if you added a top position to what you had, select this one, if you're still unsure, select the one that was posted first (would be this one).

Comment: I think your answer was first. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-top: 75%;` to `#second` div.

Because `position:absolute;` will make it's position `0, 0` so you need to give some space above to bring it down.

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bgWzb/3/)

Comment: Try removing the position absolute, and see what happens when the element has no content and the body has no height

Comment: @mohammad why 75%, I think it works with margin-top 100%, is that right?

Comment: @Nrc TRY IT AND YOU WILL SE THE RESULT.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need `position: absolute`. Just remember to give `html` and `body` a `width` and `height` property.

http://jsfiddle.net/bgWzb/4/

#### CSS

```
html,
body,
#first,
#second{
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; }

#first{
    background:blue;
}

#second{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: This is great!. It works, but I don't understand why. Can you explain it? please.

Comment: `position: absolute` removes elements from the document flow. That means they don't take up space and will just cover the page where they're positioned. So removing `position: absolute` from them allows them to take up space again. Since the `div`s are the same dimensions as the viewport the first one pushes the other one off the screen.

Comment: I understand why you remove position:absolute. But why is it necessary to give html and body width and hight 100% ?

Comment: You need to give `html` and `body` dimensions because they would normally be `0x0` since there is no content in them.

Comment: adeneo and thgaskell solutions are both equally very good. The system do not let me accept both. I do not know what criteria to use in this case?